# How to style all instances of a certain word?

Tags: color, luatex, texlive

In my document I want to change the colour of every instance of the `*` character to red.

How can I style every instance of a single word or character without interfering with the document's other styles?

Comment: Here's one approach, demonstrated on individual capital letters: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173209/change-the-color-of-capital-letters/173215#173215

Comment: Here's another one that might possibly be adapted: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165700/how-to-automatically-color-a-string-that-starts-by-a-specific-character/165722#165722.  In either case, it might be easier to do in your text editor...

Answer (score 7):

If you stick to the `*` example, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}
dofile("star.lua")
\end{luacode}

Hello * cruel * world

\end{document}
```

and `star.lua` is the following:

```lua
local GLYF = node.id("glyph")
local HLIST = node.id("hlist")
local VLIST = node.id("vlist")

local colstackstart, colstackstop
colstackstart = node.new("whatsit","pdf_colorstack")
colstackstop  = node.new("whatsit","pdf_colorstack")

colstackstart.data = "1 0 0 rg "
colstackstart.stack = 0
colstackstop.data = ""
colstackstop.stack = 0

-- one could look for the availability of the field 'cmd' instead
if status.luatex_version < 79 then
    colstackstart.cmd = 1
    colstackstop.cmd = 2
else
    colstackstart.command = 1
    colstackstop.command = 2
end



function star( head )
    local curhead, orighead = head, head
    while head do
        -- recurse into the hbox or vbox, if there are any
        if head.id == HLIST or head.id == VLIST then star(head.list)
        -- the * is ascii 42, I hope
        elseif head.id == GLYF and head.char == 42 then
            curhead = node.insert_before(curhead,head,node.copy(colstackstart))
            curhead = node.insert_after(curhead,head,node.copy(colstackstop))
        end
        head = head.next
    end
    return orighead
end



luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_linebreak_filter', star, 'colorstar')
```

This inserts a colorstack whatsit node before and after each occurence of the character with the number 42.

[image: red stars]

Comment: Will this leave e.g. `\section*[]{}` untouched? (I am not curious enough to run code I don't understand at all ;).)

Comment: @cfr it will only change the visible output, not the input.