# Format words starting with specific letter sequence

Tags: formatting, automation

Is it possible to automatically format words starting from specific letter sequence? For instance, in the text `"HalloWorld, HalloPeople, there is a nice day!"` I want the whole words starting from `"Hallo"` (case-sensitive) to be red (`"HalloWorld"` and `"HalloPeople"` in this case). Thanks!

Comment: Should the "World" and "People" substrings also be marked in red?

Comment: yes, whole words should be formatted (the question has been clarified).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are [How to style all instances of a certain word?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233484/35864), [How to automatically color a string that starts by a specific character (@)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165700/35864), [Macro: Replace all occurrences of a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165218/35864).

Comment: Thanks! I will study this solutions (I'm quite new in LaTeX).

Comment: I'd use external tools (Perl, sed in Unix/Linux, Python) for this. But then again, I'm a complete rookie programming in (La)TeX...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution, which uses LuaLaTeX, is a simple extension of the answer given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165224/5001.

The solution assumes that the string "Hallo", without any subsequent letters, should be highlighted as well. If that's not the case, just change `"(Hallo%a*)"` to `"(Hallo%a+)"` in the second argument of the `string.gsub` function.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}     
\begin{luacode}
function Hallo_Highlight ( line )
  return string.gsub(line, "(Hallo%a*)" , "\\textcolor{red}{%0}") 
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", Hallo_Highlight, "Hallo")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
Hallo xyz HalloWorld, HalloPeople! abc
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: To switch off the highlighting of the "Hallo..." words whenever a `lstlisting` environment is active, it's useful to (a) set up explicit LaTeX macros that turn highlighting on and off (called `\HighlightOn` and `\HighlightOff`, respectively, and (b) use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `lstlisting` environment so that highlighting is switched off at the *start* of a `lstlisting` environment and switched back on at the *end* of the `lstlisting` environment. The macros `\HighlightOn` and `\HighlightOff` can also be used in other parts of the document; do make sure, though, to alternate the use of the macros. I.e., don't use `\HighlightOn` twice (or more times) in a row; ditto for `\HighlightOff`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacode,luatexbase}     
\begin{luacode}
function Highlight ( line )
  line = string.gsub (line, "(Hallo%a*)" , "\\textcolor{red}{%0}") 
  return ( line )
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\HighlightOn{\luaexec{%
  luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer",  
              Highlight, "Highlight" )}}
\newcommand\HighlightOff{\luaexec{%
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_input_buffer', 
              "Highlight" )}}
\HighlightOn  % switch on highlighting of "Hallo..." strings

\usepackage{listings,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\HighlightOff}
\AtEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\HighlightOn}

\begin{document}
Hallo xyz HalloWorld, HalloPeople! abc

\begin{lstlisting}
Write('HalloWorld');
\end{lstlisting}

Hallo xyz HalloWorld, HalloPeople! abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm ) Lua seems to be very powerful tool.

Comment: Is it possible to check in `Hallo_Highlight` function, which environment the `line` comes from? In particular, I need to ignore formatting if the matched words are in `lstlisting` environment.

Comment: @Oleg - Please see the addendum to my answer.